# Fuseki SPARQL Query: Regex not finding existing literal

Tags: regex, sparql

I am trying to return a node based on a regex query.

```
select ?s ?p where {  
    ?s a Products:Style .
    ?s Products:PartNumber ?p .
    filter ( regex (?p, "^442A")) 
}
```

I have a node with named Products:442A30. It has the following attributes.

```
Products:442A30  a                    <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> , Products:Style ;
        rdfs:label                    "Gesture; Chair, Upholstered ;
        Products:AltDescription       "Gesture;Chair,Uph,Adj seat D" ;
        Products:BasePrice            "1,241.00" ;
        Products:ClassNoun            "Chair" ;
        Products:HasComponent         Products:P442_WORK_1 ;
        Products:HasServicePart       Products:4652510SR ;
        Products:LongDescription      "Gesture; Chair, Upholstered, Shell back, Adjustable seat depth" ;
        Products:PartNumber           "442A30" ;
        Products:ProductLine          Products:442_GESTURE ;
        Products:ShortDescription     "Gesture;Chair,Uph,Shl bk,Adj seat D" ;
        Products:StyleFeature         "Shell back" , "Adjustable seat depth" ;
        Products:StyleMaterial        "Upholstered" ;
```

Unless I am mistaken, both of my query parameters are being met. Despite this, the node above is not returned. Instead, I get `Products:442A30VP` and `Products:442B30VP`.

Thanks!

Comment: Given the resource and the query, and assuming the prefixes align, I don't see how the resource would not be returned by the query. Are you sure the data in the db is as shown here?

Answer (score 1):

Change your filter to `filter ( regex (?p, "^442.*"))`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it does not help. I did leave out one bit of information. The data was recently migrated from another Fuskei DB. This search works in the old DB but in the new DB it does not. Even though I can `describe` the product in the new DB, it still won't show up.